# where to store jasypt decryption password

Tags: java, security, jasypt

I am developing a java swing utility, whichever store the email id's password and other sensitive values (i.e. database user id and password, etc.) in encrypted form inside properties file using **jasypt**.

At Runtime I use the same encrypted password inside the java class, suppose "abcd12345@" to decrypt and retrieve the properties values again using **jasypt**.

So, here I have secured my values after encryption inside th properties file using **jasypt** but using **JD Project, Cavaj, DJ Java Decompilers** nowadays it is very easy to view the source code, thus to view my **jasypt** password from java class file!

Now, I want to know that Where and How could I hide/store the **jasypt** decrypting password inside my swing project jar?

**How can I hide above password safely inside the jar?**

Comment: Kindly someone help me or give some suggestions to me...

Comment: I am apparently waiting for a reply, please someone help me...

Answer (score 0):

This is not that straight forward to solve and also depends on the context in which your Swing utility will be distributed.

There is a similar [question on security stackexchange that contains an answer in a broader context](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption).

Taking the above case into account the options in which the password is provided as an argument at startup seems to be the most elegant one as I assume that the usage of hardware modules are not really an option.